# PHPMailer sends duplicate emails

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, phpmailer

**PROBLEM:** I'm receiving three duplicate emails for each user who signs up with their email address. My guest list is being overrun by duplicate emails, and I don't know what's wrong with my code.

> **Probable Cause**: I have 3 signup forms, so I think somehow when I submit one signup form they all submit at the same time. The problem lies in either the Bootstrap 4.1.3 JS or the HTML.

**PHP Code:**

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

// Popup Form Signup
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.domain.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "user@domain.com"; 
$mail->Password = "password"; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';                           
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->setFrom('$email', 'Guest');
$mail->addAddress('admin@domain.com', 'Admin');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "New Member!";
$mail->Body = $email;
$mail->AltBody = $email;

$mail2 = new PHPMailer();
$mail2->IsSMTP();
$mail2->Host = "mail.domain.com"; 
$mail2->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail2->Username = "user@domain.com"; 
$mail2->Password = "password"; 
$mail2->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';                      
$mail2->Port = 587;                             
$mail2->setFrom('support@domain.com', 'Support');
$mail2->AddAddress("$email");    
$mail2->AddReplyTo('support@domain.com');

    $mail2->Subject = "Thanks for signing up!";
    $message = '';
    $mail2->Body = $message;
    $mail2->AltBody = $message;


    if(!$mail2->Send())
    {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Please reload the page and try again. <p>";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail2->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
    }

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
    echo "Message was not received. Please reload the page and try again.<p>";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
    }
```

I also have other Forms that open different PHP files, but they shouldn't be the issue here. I just added it here just in case anyone can figure something out.

**FORM 1 (Same Landing Page)**

```
<form class="signupForm1 input-group mt-1" method="post" action="topconfirm">
        <div class="input-group">
        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Enter your email address</label>
        <input style ="overflow:hidden;" id="email" type="email" name="email" required class="sentence form-control" aria-label="Large" placeholder="enter your email address">      
        <button style="font-size:17px;" name="topsubmit" type="submit" class="ctabutton semibolder submitButton sentence text-white btn btn-secondary px-lg-3 px-md-1 px-sm-1 btn-lg rounded-0">Get Started</button>
        </div>              
</form>
```

**FORM 2 (Same Landing Page)**

```
<form class="signupForm2 input-group mt-1" method="post" action="bottomconfirm">
                <div class="input-group">
                <label style="font-weight:normal!important;" for="email" class="sr-only">Enter your email address</label>
                <input style ="overflow:hidden;"  id="email" type="email" name="email" required class="sentence form-control" aria-label="Large" placeholder="enter your email address">         
                <input style="font-size:17px;" name="footersubmit" type="submit" class="ctabutton semibolder submitButton sentence text-white btn btn-secondary px-lg-3 px-md-1 px-sm-1 btn-lg rounded-0" value="Get Started"/>
                </div>              
        </form>
```

I'm not a JavaScript or PHP mailer expert someone please show me how to fix this problem, I think it might be a Bootstrap JS 4.13. Any suggestion or help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you dont need to initialise PHPMailer twice to send 2 emails. your also using php's mail() as well as phpmailer, this is a bit of a mess to be honest.

Comment: Having an input with the same name in different forms shouldn't matter. You can only submit one form at a time.

Comment: whats your jquery looking like? you have same #id on the same page. what is the confirm in your action for? you should leave it empty

Comment: The confirm triggers the confirm.php page that sends the email upon entering a valid email and hitting the submit button

Comment: phpmailer can be cleaned up to like half the code if you use variables and swap them out based on a  if(isset($_POST['variable']))

Comment: you're initializing PHPMailer twice and also using PHP's `mail()` method, why?

Comment: I don't really know the difference, can you please provide a sample of the code? What do you mean I'm using PHP Mail and PHP Mailer? I'm a big time novice in PHP.

Comment: @ChosenJuan Comment out `mail()` and see the results

Comment: Comment out mail() where exactly? What line?

Comment: @ChosenJuan `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` and you should you `if($mail->Send())` instead of `(!$mail->Send())` , that's how they've shown in the docs

Comment: The `!` in the condition does not affect sending, only what you do with the result. You don’t need any of the code relating to `$headers`. It’s quite common for browser plugins to cause repeat form submissions, so use logging to spot that happening.

Comment: I just updated the code @Synchro according to the latest phpmailer code, but I still get the same problem. I'm deducing it stems from the jQuery submit script.

Comment: Logging will reveal duplicate requests

Comment: How do I go about logging?

Comment: @ChosenJuan I think you are not using the answers properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a seperate submit()-function (with the onclick-handler) for each button and removing the `value='submit'` from them, like so:

```
    <!--signupform1-->
    <form class="signupForm1 input-group mt-1" method="post" action="topconfirm">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="email" class="sr-only">Enter your email address</label>
            <input style ="overflow:hidden;" id="email" type="email" name="email" required class="sentence form-control" aria-label="Large" placeholder="enter your email address">      
            <button style="font-size:17px;" name="topsubmit" type="button" class="ctabutton semibolder submitButton sentence text-white btn btn-secondary px-lg-3 px-md-1 px-sm-1 btn-lg rounded-0" onclick="submit1();">Get Started</button>
        </div>              
    </form>

    <!--signupform2-->
    <form class="signupForm2 input-group mt-1" method="post" action="bottomconfirm">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label style="font-weight:normal!important;" for="email" class="sr-only">Enter your email address</label>
            <input style ="overflow:hidden;"  id="email" type="email" name="email" required class="sentence form-control" aria-label="Large" placeholder="enter your email address">         
            <input style="font-size:17px;" name="footersubmit" type="button" class="ctabutton semibolder submitButton sentence text-white btn btn-secondary px-lg-3 px-md-1 px-sm-1 btn-lg rounded-0" onclick="submit2();" value="Get Started"/>
        </div>              
    </form>
```

And then in your js:

```
<script>
    function submit1() {
        $(".signupForm1").submit();
    }
    function submit2() {
        $(".signupForm2").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This answer works best, it was the submit button that was causing the issue. However, in order to get it to work, I had to add the type="submit" to the buttons on both the forms. So far, I've been getting individual email from each form. Cheers!!! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

First off: Bootstrap ain't the culprit here, JS neither. And if if PHP (or php mailer) are clean too, then you may want to take a look at the mail server settings (check with your host).

However, maybe the form is submitted twice? Let's check:

1. open google chrome debugger (F12)
2. Click on "Network", tick "Preserve log"
3. Click on "Clear" (2nd icon left)
4. Run your regular script (i.e. fill the form and submit)
5. "Network" tab will show you any duplicate call of your PHP page

If it still fails, try this:

download https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

create a completely blank file, directly put your PHP emailing lines in it. Remove the form, input, javascript, isset and the rest. Run this file by simply calling it, so it would look like:

```
    require_once("PHPMailerAutoload.php"); // <---- only this will be required (put your path properly)

    $mail2 = new PHPMailer();
    $mail2->IsSMTP();
    $mail2->Host = "mail.domain.com"; 
    $mail2->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail2->Username = "user@domain.com"; 
    $mail2->Password = "password"; 
    $mail2->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';                      
    $mail2->Port = 587;                             
    $mail2->setFrom('support@domain.com', 'Support');
    $mail2->AddAddress("$email");    
    $mail2->AddReplyTo('support@domain.com');

    $mail2->Subject = "Thanks for signing up!";
    $message = '';
    $mail2->Body = $message;
    $mail2->AltBody = $message;


    if(!$mail2->Send())
    {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Please reload the page and try again. 
    <p>";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail2->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
    }
```

godd luck

Comment: Thanks for the debugger tutorial, it's very valuable. However, my log didn't particularly show anything wrong with the code as I submitted the email to the form. Seems like it needed a JS solution to fix it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ChosenJuan I guess most of us missed it: one should never bind a JS form submit event to an html submit button to begin with. :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of PHPMailer you're using but you're also using PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) method, which is quite ironic because you're also using PHPMailer. But nevertheless, this is how I did it in one of my projects :

```
function sendAuthEmail($email, $token, $role) {
        try {
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; //SMTP Debug
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = 'example@example.com';
            $mail->Password = 'password';
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail->Port = '587';
            /**
             * SMTPOptions work-around by @author : Synchro
             * This setting should removed on server and
             * mailing should be working on the server
             */
            $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );

            // Recipients

            $mail->setFrom('no-reply@confirmation.com', 'Do Not Reply');
            $mail->addAddress($email, 'Yash Karanke'); // Add a recipient
            $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@confirmation.com');

            // Content

            $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Authentication Email';
            $mail->Body = 'text to send';
            if ($mail->send()) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
                exit();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception $e) {
            return $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }
```

If you're looking for a simpler example, remove the wrapped function and use only code which you need. More details on [Docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example)

In your code you're using `if(!$mail->send())` which I'm not sure, how it is working, but you should use `if($mail->send())` which is recommended way from the docs

This code snippet is from verion 6.0.3.

Comment: When I comment out mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); it doesn't work, but I did remove the $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ; and it worked without it. However, your above solution is not working and I'm still receiving duplicate emails.

Comment: Please check the new updated PHPMailer code, now I think the issue has to do with jQuery submit script. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @ChosenJuan Yes, I checked and there is no conflict with jQuery Code.

Comment: yes, I actually removed the jQuery completely, it wasn't even necessary. I think the problem is that it submits all three forms at the same time, but I have no idea how to fix this issue while keeping all three forms. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that a deep dive into your jQuery / JS code could bring the answer, but my guess is that the `button` elements in your forms trigger some event that affects the other forms.

Did you try changing all the buttons to `<input type='submit'/>`?

Comment: I tried changing the input to submit, but that isn't working either. The only JQuery code in question could be the Jquery Validation code I will post it soon

Answer (score 0):

start a session in your server and store the mail sent information

```
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

// Popup Form Signup
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.domain.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "user@domain.com"; 
$mail->Password = "password"; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';                           
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->setFrom('$email', 'Guest');
$mail->addAddress('admin@domain.com', 'Admin');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "New Member!";
$mail->Body = $email;
$mail->AltBody = $email;

$mail2 = new PHPMailer();
$mail2->IsSMTP();
$mail2->Host = "mail.domain.com"; 
$mail2->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail2->Username = "user@domain.com"; 
$mail2->Password = "password"; 
$mail2->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';                      
$mail2->Port = 587;                             
$mail2->setFrom('support@domain.com', 'Support');
$mail2->AddAddress("$email");    
$mail2->AddReplyTo('support@domain.com');

    $mail2->Subject = "Thanks for signing up!";
    $message = '';
    $mail2->Body = $message;
    $mail2->AltBody = $message;


if(!$_SESSION['is_mail_1_send']){//check mail sended once
    if(!$mail2->Send())
    {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Please reload the page and try again. <p>";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail2->ErrorInfo;
   $_SESSION['is_mail_1_send']=false;
 exit;
    }else{
            $_SESSION['is_mail_1_send']=true;   
    }
}
if(!$_SESSION['is_mail_2_send']){//check mail sended once
    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
    echo "Message was not received. Please reload the page and try again.<p>";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
$_SESSION['is_mail_2_send']=false;
    exit;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['is_mail_2_send']=true;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, It still send the duplicate emails. Is this supposed to send the logs to my email?

Comment: how many emails you received by using my session setting i tried my code it sending only 2mails

Comment: It keeps sending three duplicate emails to the user from support@domain.com and three duplicate emails to my admin@domain.com

Answer (score 0):

> Where you are handling form submit event?  Create a separate function
>   for sending mail.  call that function when user click on specific form
>   submit button. like below

```
// Your separate Mail sending function
sendMail(arg1, arg2, arg3){
   // PHP Mailer Configurations
}

// Calling your first form
if(isset($_POST['topsubmit']){
  sendMail(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

// Calling your second form
if(isset($_POST['footersubmit']){
  sendMail(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to incorporate the above code?  Should I just copy the sendmail part and place it above or should it replace something?  And the second code should just replace the if if(!$mail->Send()) code? Can you please update your sample?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['topsubmit']){
  if(!$mail->Send())  // like this should work.  
}

// But if you send mail related full configuration to a separate function it's a lot batter.

Comment: Can I just add this one send function replacing both if(!$mail->Send()) functions // Calling your first form
if(isset($_POST['topsubmit']){
  sendMail($mail, $mail2);
echo "Message could not be sent. Please go back to voozlr.com and try again. If problem persists contact us at voozlr.com/contact. Thank you for your patience!<p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail, $mail2->ErrorInfo;
exit;
  }

Comment: if(isset($_POST['footersubmit']){ if(!$mail2->Send()) 
{
echo "Message could not be sent. Please go back to voozlr.com and try again. If problem persists contact us at voozlr.com/contact. Thank you for your patience!<p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail2->ErrorInfo;
exit;
} it's not working. Am I doing something wrong? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand it correctly?  o_O

Of course, with that php code, you are sending multiple emails.

just change your php code like this, so you parse the `mail1` and `mail2` conditionally separated:

```
if (!empty($_POST['topsubmit']))
{
    $mail2 = new PHPMailer();
    ...
    if(!$mail2->Send())
    ...
}

if (!empty($_POST['footersubmit']))
{
    $mail2 = new PHPMailer();
    ...
    if(!$mail2->Send())
    ...
}
```

thus, all of the emails wont be sent on the same pageload.

Comment: I'm sending two emails at the same time. One email: $mail to myself at admin.domain.com and another email: $mail2 to the user who entered their email.  But what you answered is splitting the top submit and footersubmit, but I split the topsubmit and footersubmit into separate PHP files labelled topconfirm.php and footerconfirm.php both of these php files send two emails each at mail and mail2 one to the new signup and one to me. How do I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete answer to my question, thanks to @SearchingSolutions for showing me the correct way to solve this issue.

What I did to fix this problem was to create 2 different buttons with separate onclick-handlers for each button. Each button has different ids and I added the **TYPE="Submit"** on both. I gave every form a different name, and added a small JS script to submit the specific form when the specific onclick handler is called.

So far, every email is coming in as intended, and everything is running smoothly again.

**Thank you all for the great answers!**

**The HTML:**

```
<form class="signupForm1 input-group mt-1" method="post" action="topconfirm">
        <div class="input-group">
        <label for="email2" class="sr-only">Enter your email address</label>
        <input style ="overflow:hidden;" id="email2" type="email" name="email2" required class="sentence form-control" aria-label="Large" placeholder="enter your email address">        
        <button style="font-size:17px;" name="topsubmit" type="submit" class="ctabutton semibolder sentence text-white btn btn-secondary px-lg-3 px-md-1 px-sm-1 btn-lg rounded-0" onclick="submit1();">Get Started"</button>
        </div>              
</form>


<form class="signupForm2 input-group mt-1" method="post" action="footerconfirm">
        <div class="input-group">
        <label style="font-weight:normal!important;" for="email3" class="sr-only">Enter your email address</label>
        <input style ="overflow:hidden;"  id="email3" type="email" name="email3" required class="sentence form-control" aria-label="Large" placeholder="enter your email address">       
        <button style="font-size:17px;" name="footersubmit" type="submit" class="ctabutton semibolder sentence text-white btn btn-secondary px-lg-3 px-md-1 px-sm-1 btn-lg rounded-0" onclick="submit2();">Get Started"</button>
        </div>              
</form>
```

**The JS Script:**

```
<script>
function submit1() {
    $(".signupForm1").submit();
}
function submit2() {
    $(".signupForm2").submit();
}
```